# Get value from select option by searching/filtering partial option text and output value as jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, select, select-options

I have a selectbox on a page which looks like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" autocomplete="off" class="inputbox input-large">
 <option value="">- Select option -</option>
 <option value="1">Car</option>
 <option value="12">- Plane</option>
 <option value="34">- - Train</option>
</select>
```

On the same page I also have a input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" value="Train">
```

Now I need to return the value `34`. The selectbox option does not have to be selected I just need to have the number that is within the value field. So if the input would read `Plane` it should return `12`. Furthermore I would need this value to be a variable so I can use it further down the line in jQuery.

I have been trying to get this now for over an hour but with most examples on the net it is always about making the option selected and I simply have not found a example on returning the value.

What I have so far is not even half of what I need but I include it so that everyone can see that I am trying.

```
  $str = $('#myInput').val();

  var exists = false;
  $("#mySelect option").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().replace(/-/g,"").trim() == $str;
      var exists = true;
  });
  console.log(exists);
```

For everyone who is willing to put down a code example please start from scratch as the above is probably wrong in a hundred different ways ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're too far away:

The `return` here:

```
    return $(this).text().replace(/-/g,"").trim() == $str;
    exists = true;
```

stops the `exists = true` in the next line from running - `return` exits the (anonymous filter) function at that point and no code after it runs (within that function).

There are two options that spring to mind without changing your code too much

- use `.filter` then check the result
- use `.each` and set `exists` within the loop

In the second case, using `each = each || [test]` means it will stay `true` once set - if you were using a simple `for` then you would add a `break` once found.

```js
$str = $('#myInput').val();

var exists = false;
var filtered = $("#mySelect option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/-/g, "").trim() == $str;
});
exists = filtered.length > 0;

console.log(exists);

exists = false;
$("#mySelect option").each(function() {
  exists = exists || $(this).text().replace(/-/g, "").trim() == $str;
});
console.log(exists);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" autocomplete="off" class="inputbox input-large">
  <option value="">- Select option -</option>
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="12">- Plane</option>
  <option value="34">- - Train</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" value="Train">
```

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what was needed!